# Powershell run programs with arguements as different users

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Simple (or so i thought) at startup Script for my Work Machine.

For this i need to mainly open

IE
Firefox as logged in user
Firefox as Admin user
Outlook as main profile

I'm looking to do this with Powershell - any ideas on how to achieve the running as admin user for Firefox as I have managed to get the rest working.

Comment: You need to show your existing code if you want some help.

Comment: I have been using Shortcuts whilest making use of the Runas Command

For example 
'code' "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote

and


C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:Domain\User2 "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote" 'code'

Comment: You can configure a shortcut to use Runas by default in the Advanced Properties.

Comment: I have managed to create a shortcut to do this - Was ok for when i needed to open only 1 item but now i'm looking at having 3 instances of Firefox open at one time ( all as different users) but i cannot get the no-remote parameter to function as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a credentials object with the proper ones in it, and then run the app you want with it like this:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process filefullpath.exe -WorkingDirectory path_here -Credential ($credentials)
```

Got it from [here](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/9502.aspx).

Comment: I have been using the above but cannot push the parameter "no-remote" along with this as well

Comment: What's "no-remote"? couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: No-Remote is the Firefox parameter that forces each new instance of firefox to open as a seperate process - otherwise you open firefox with User1 then try open it with user2 and it just opens a new Window as User1

Comment: Than just add it to "start-process" with "-ArgumentList".
Can't test at the moment, I'll try later today.

Comment: I have been trying this yet When i Run it All i see happen is that a new tab in the current window appears - where this should force a new Window to Appear instead

Comment: Would it be better to force this to run in a New powershell Window (as the account i want Firefox to then open in) and run this there?

Comment: Can you post your relevant code?

Answer (score -1):

My script is as follows

This would be run by DOMAIN\User1

```
$username1 = "Domain\user2"
$username2 = "Domain\User1_adm"
$password = "Passw0rd!"
$credentials1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList    @($username1,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$credentials2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username2,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$Args1 = "-no-remote"
$Args2 = "no-merge"

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList $Args1 -Credential ($credentials1)
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList $Args1 -Credential ($credentials2)
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
Start-Process "iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList $Args2 -Credential ($credentials1)
Start-Process "iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList $Args2 -Credential ($credentials2)
Start-Process "iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList $Args2
```